# Reading json file using d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I wrote a code that reads a csv file using d3.js. My csv file is

> x1,y1,x2,y2 
>   2.0000,0.0000,-4.0000,1.5000 
>   1.9800,0.0000,-3.9500,1.5000 
>   1.9600,0.0000,-3.9000,1.5000 
>   1.9400,0.0000,-3.8500,1.5000 
>   1.9200,0.0000,-3.8000,1.5000

and my code that reads this file is

```
d3.csv("./data.csv", function(err, data){
    data1 = data.map(function(d) { return [ +d["x1"], +d["y1"] ]; });
    data2 = data.map(function(d) { return [ +d["x2"], +d["y2"] ]; });})
```

This code reads csv file and save its data into array, data1 and data2.

And each array looks like

> data1[0][0] = 2.0000, data1[0][1] = 0.0000
>   data1[1][0] = 1.9800, data1[1][1] = 0.0000
>   data1[2][0] = 1.9600, data1[2][1] = 0.0000

Now, I want to do exactly same thing with reading json data.
My json code is

```
var inputdata = [
{"y2": "1.5000", "x2": "-4.0000","y1": "0.0000", "x1": "2.0000"},
{"y2": "1.5000", "x2": "-3.9500","y1": "0.0000", "x1": "1.9800"},
{"y2": "1.5000", "x2": "-3.9000","y1": "0.0000", "x1": "1.9600"},
{"y2": "1.5000", "x2": "-3.8500","y1": "0.0000", "x1": "1.9400"},
{"y2": "1.5000", "x2": "-3.8000","y1": "0.0000", "x1": "1.9200"},
];
```

Then how do I read this json code and put data into array data1 and data2 like above csv code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var inputdata = [
{"y2": "1.5000", "x2": "-4.0000","y1": "0.0000", "x1": "2.0000"},
{"y2": "1.5000", "x2": "-3.9500","y1": "0.0000", "x1": "1.9800"},
{"y2": "1.5000", "x2": "-3.9000","y1": "0.0000", "x1": "1.9600"},
{"y2": "1.5000", "x2": "-3.8500","y1": "0.0000", "x1": "1.9400"},
{"y2": "1.5000", "x2": "-3.8000","y1": "0.0000", "x1": "1.9200"},
];
    data1 = inputdata.map(function(d) { return [ +d["x1"], +d["y1"] ]; });
    data2 = inputdata.map(function(d) { return [ +d["x2"], +d["y2"] ]; });
//do your task with data1 and data2
```